# Executing a function in command line after calling "sudo su"

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi

I'm currently working on a program that is constantly checking the utilization of the available CPU cores on a raspberry pi and then calculates what the optimal frequency the CPU should be running on. However, I am running into some issues with executing the function that actually changes the CPU frequency.

My current code snippet is as follows

```
system("cd ~; cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0; sudo su;")
```

However, I haven't been able to find a method to get it to then execute the last command

```
echo //some_frequency > scaling_setspeed
```

I've tried the following

```
int freq = //some number
char buf[BIFSIZ]
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "cd ~; cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0; sudo su; echo %d > scaling_setspeed", freq);
system(buf)
```

as well as using

```
system("cd ~; cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0; sudo su;")
cout << "echo " << freq << " > scaling_setspeed" << endl;
```

and

```
system("cd ~; cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0; sudo su;")    
printf("echo %d > scaling_setspeed");
```

None of these have worked.

I realize this question probably has an obvious solution that I'm just oblivious to, but I am unable to determine how to get this to work, any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: How about `sudo -E /usr/bin/printf %d > scaling_setspeed`?

Comment: Using shell commands for this is the wrong approach. You should run your program (or parts of it) as `root` or another user with sufficient permissions/capabilities. Then you open the file you want to write to just like any other file in C++.

Comment: I am also not sure _why_ you are doing this. The kernel already has modules for this, optimized for specific CPUs. Just set the policy for cpufreq to `ondemand`/`schedutil` or maybe `performance`/`powersave` depending on what is more important to you.